# Как рассчитать фактическую пропускную способность памяти в ядре программы CUDA (т.е. рассчитать фактический bandwidth ядра)?

Tags: c++, cuda

Есть некоторое ядро (она же функция, которая выполняется на GPU). Также у меня есть замер времени выполнения ядра (у меня это переменная gpuTime, в которой сохраняется результат в миллисекундах).
**Вопрос:** как рассчитать пропускную способность памяти (Bandwidth) в ядре?
Имею сведения, что нужно вначале значение обрабатываемое на ядре (в моем случае это матрица int размерностью NxM; т.е. N * M * sizeof(int)) разделить на gpuTime и потом что-то с этим еще сделать, но вот что - не знаю.
У меня видеокарта GTX940MX (с типом DDR3), ее теоретический bandwidth = 16.02 GB/s.
А мне по сути нужно рассчитать в ядре фактический bandwidth

Answer (score 2):

Вместо велосипедов со счетчиками следует воспользоваться [профилировщиком памяти от вендора](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#memory-chart). Кроме того, следует отметить, что организация памяти в CUDA иерархическая, чтение из глобальной памяти осуществляется через кеш второго уровня, а у каждого блока есть еще кеш первого уровня и отдельная разделяемая память, так что счетчиков памяти много.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Как обычно, сначала спрашиваю, а потом уже начинаю думать и вникать...
В общем, вот решение моего вопроса:
На ядре обрабатывается только матрица int размерностью N на M.
Cчитаю объем обрабатываемой памяти: N * M * sizeof(int) - это в байтах, нужно перевести в гигабайты, т.е. это значение 3 раза делим на 1024.
Моя переменная gpuTime измеряется в миллисекундах, мне нужны секунды, поэтому делим это значение на 1000.
Итоговое решение мне нужно в Gb/s: просто делим два предыдущих числа друг на друга (т.е. (N * M * sizeof(int) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) / (gpuTime / 1000))